running jdownloader in portainer is unreachable in browser on configured port
i have a raspberry pi 4 with portainer installed. currently there is only a pihole instance (network_mode=host) running, but i want to add jdownloader and after that, home assistant. Well, but i can't get the jdownloader instance running... or, to be more precise, i can't connect to the running instance.
I am an absolute portainer beginner, but i decided to run my containers as a portainer stack. Thats probably a more advanced feature, but i like the fact that i have all information (network, shares, name, environment) at one place and i can add comments what the specific setting does.
This is my composer script:

services:
  jdownloader-2:
    container_name: jdownloader
    image: jlesage/jdownloader-2:latest
    network_mode: host
    ports:                               # Ports used in this container
      - 5800:5800/tcp                         # GUI via Browser
      #- 5900:5900/tcp                         # GUI via VNC
      - 3129:3129/tcp                         # MyJDownloader
    volumes:
      - '/data/compose/jdownloader-2/config:/config:rw'
      - '/data/compose/jdownloader-2/downloads:/output:rw'
    environment:
      LANG: de_DE.UTF-8
      TZ: 'Europe/Berlin'
      KEEP_APP_RUNNING: 1
      VNC_LISTENING_PORT: -1                                  # Disable VNC
      MYJDOWNLOADER_EMAIL: 'xxx'
      MYJDOWNLOADER_PASSWORD: 'yyy'
      MYJDOWNLOADER_DEVICE_NAME: 'zzz'
      JDOWNLOADER_HEADLESS: 1                                 # No UI, just remote control
    restart: unless-stopped

The script deploys and the container says its running. The logs do not show any errors or problems:
[cont-env    ] GSK_RENDERER: executing...
[cont-env    ] GSK_RENDERER: terminated successfully.
[cont-env    ] GSK_RENDERER: loading...
[cont-env    ] GTK2_RC_FILES: executing...
[cont-env    ] GTK2_RC_FILES: terminated successfully.
[cont-env    ] GTK2_RC_FILES: not setting variable.
[cont-env    ] GTK_THEME: executing...
[cont-env    ] GTK_THEME: terminated successfully.
[cont-env    ] GTK_THEME: not setting variable.
[cont-env    ] HOME: loading...
[cont-env    ] INSTALL_PACKAGES_INTERNAL: executing...
[cont-env    ] INSTALL_PACKAGES_INTERNAL: terminated successfully.
[cont-env    ] INSTALL_PACKAGES_INTERNAL: not setting variable.
[cont-env    ] LIBGL_DRIVERS_PATH: executing...
[cont-env    ] LIBGL_DRIVERS_PATH: terminated successfully.
[cont-env    ] LIBGL_DRIVERS_PATH: loading...
[cont-env    ] PULSE_CONFIG_PATH: executing...
[cont-env    ] PULSE_CONFIG_PATH: terminated successfully.
[cont-env    ] PULSE_CONFIG_PATH: not setting variable.
[cont-env    ] PULSE_COOKIE: executing...
[cont-env    ] PULSE_COOKIE: terminated successfully.
[cont-env    ] PULSE_COOKIE: not setting variable.
[cont-env    ] PULSE_SERVER: executing...
[cont-env    ] PULSE_SERVER: terminated successfully.
[cont-env    ] PULSE_SERVER: not setting variable.
[cont-env    ] QT_STYLE_OVERRIDE: executing...
[cont-env    ] QT_STYLE_OVERRIDE: terminated successfully.
[cont-env    ] QT_STYLE_OVERRIDE: not setting variable.
[cont-env    ] TAKE_CONFIG_OWNERSHIP: loading...
[cont-env    ] XDG_CACHE_HOME: loading...
[cont-env    ] XDG_CONFIG_HOME: loading...
[cont-env    ] XDG_DATA_HOME: loading...
[cont-env    ] XDG_RUNTIME_DIR: loading...
[cont-env    ] XDG_STATE_HOME: loading...
[cont-env    ] container environment variables initialized.
[cont-secrets] loading container secrets...
[cont-secrets] container secrets loaded.
[cont-init   ] executing container initialization scripts...
[cont-init   ] 10-certs.sh: executing...
[cont-init   ] 10-certs.sh: terminated successfully.
[cont-init   ] 10-check-app-niceness.sh: executing...
[cont-init   ] 10-check-app-niceness.sh: terminated successfully.
[cont-init   ] 10-clean-logmonitor-states.sh: executing...
[cont-init   ] 10-clean-logmonitor-states.sh: terminated successfully.
[cont-init   ] 10-clean-tmp-dir.sh: executing...
[cont-init   ] 10-clean-tmp-dir.sh: terminated successfully.
[cont-init   ] 10-fontconfig-cache-dir.sh: executing...
[cont-init   ] 10-fontconfig-cache-dir.sh: terminated successfully.
[cont-init   ] 10-init-users.sh: executing...
[cont-init   ] 10-init-users.sh: terminated successfully.
[cont-init   ] 10-nginx.sh: executing...
[cont-init   ] 10-nginx.sh: terminated successfully.
[cont-init   ] 10-openbox.sh: executing...
[cont-init   ] 10-openbox.sh: terminated successfully.
[cont-init   ] 10-pkgs-mirror.sh: executing...
[cont-init   ] 10-pkgs-mirror.sh: terminated successfully.
[cont-init   ] 10-pulse.sh: executing...
[cont-init   ] 10-pulse.sh: terminated successfully.
[cont-init   ] 10-set-tmp-dir-perms.sh: executing...
[cont-init   ] 10-set-tmp-dir-perms.sh: terminated successfully.
[cont-init   ] 10-vnc-password.sh: executing...
[cont-init   ] 10-vnc-password.sh: terminated successfully.
[cont-init   ] 10-web-data.sh: executing...
[cont-init   ] 10-web-data.sh: terminated successfully.
[cont-init   ] 10-webauth.sh: executing...
[cont-init   ] 10-webauth.sh: terminated successfully.
[cont-init   ] 10-x11-unix.sh: executing...
[cont-init   ] 10-x11-unix.sh: terminated successfully.
[cont-init   ] 10-xdg-runtime-dir.sh: executing...
[cont-init   ] 10-xdg-runtime-dir.sh: terminated successfully.
[cont-init   ] 15-cjk-font.sh: executing...
[cont-init   ] 15-cjk-font.sh: terminated successfully.
[cont-init   ] 15-install-pkgs.sh: executing...
[cont-init   ] 15-install-pkgs.sh: terminated successfully.
[cont-init   ] 55-jdownloader2.sh: executing...
[cont-init   ] 55-jdownloader2.sh: terminated successfully.
[cont-init   ] 85-take-config-ownership.sh: executing...
[cont-init   ] 85-take-config-ownership.sh: terminated successfully.
[cont-init   ] 89-info.sh: executing...
    ╭――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――╮
    │                                                                      │
    │ Application:           JDownloader 2                                 │
    │ Application Version:   n/a                                           │
    │ Docker Image Version:  24.09.1                                       │
    │ Docker Image Platform: linux/arm64                                   │
    │                                                                      │
    ╰――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――╯
[cont-init   ] 89-info.sh: terminated successfully.
[cont-init   ] all container initialization scripts executed.
[init        ] giving control to process supervisor.
[supervisor  ] loading services...
[supervisor  ] loading service 'default'...
[supervisor  ] loading service 'app'...
[supervisor  ] loading service 'logmonitor'...
[supervisor  ] service 'logmonitor' is disabled.
[supervisor  ] loading service 'logrotate'...
[supervisor  ] all services loaded.
[supervisor  ] starting services...
[supervisor  ] starting service 'app'...
[supervisor  ] all services started.

But when i open the raspberry/docker/portainer ip on port 5800 in the browser i get an ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED error. That reads like there is nothing listening on port 5800 on that ip...?
I am pretty sure thats NOT a jdownloader problem, but a configuration (or understanding) problem on my side. Can someone help/explain what i am missing or doing wrong?

It seems that JDOWNLOADER_HEADLESS: 1 disables the browser ui. I removed the line from the script, deployed it and a few minutes later, it worked.
